# Slider height settings

Tags: slideshow

I'm new to WordPress and love the themes with slider banners. it appears that in trying out a couple of themes i have changed something which has resulted in the banner being tiny.

I have kind of figured out that the 24px in the line below is driving the height - as if I change it to say 324 it starts to be ok but as soon as the next image is called it goes back to tiny.

```
div class="bx-viewport" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative; height: 24px;"><div class="bx-slider" style="width: auto; position: relative;">
```

Can someone give me a clue how to fix it?

Comment: Can you send URL? Have you tried with tag inspector to detect what div needs to be targeted?

Comment: The only themes which are covered here are the default themes.

Answer (score 0):

On of the themes you tested (I guess not in preview, but just switching it active) had only small image sizes registered via [`add_image_size()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size). There's a very popular plugin that you can use to "fix" that: [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/).